# How do you join a list to a dictionary of lists as a new item - python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Maybe a simple question:

In python I have a list of dictionaries and I want to add a list as new item in every dictionary in the list?

For example I have the list of dictionaries:

```
list_dict =[{'id':1, 'text':'John'},
            {'id':2, 'text':'Amy'},
            {'id':3, 'text':'Ron'}]
```

And a list:

```
list_age = [23, 54, 41]
```

How could I then add the list to produce the list of dictionaries:

```
list_dict =[{'id':1, 'text':'John', 'age':23},
            {'id':2, 'text':'Amy', 'age':54},
            {'id':3, 'text':'Ron', 'age':41}]
```

I am unsure of the correct code to use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could work

```
for index, item in enumerate(list_age):
  list_dict[index]['age'] = item
```

Edit:
As [@Netwave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695172/netwave) mentioned, you should make sure that `len(list_age)` is not greater than `len(list_dict)`.

Comment: yes! Why everyone else were using zip(), I can't understand, since this is the more intuitive way  to go

Comment: Yeah, I also find enumerate to be a more simple solution.

Comment: Yeah, it is a good solution. Just notice that you are modifying the list_dict, so the size should be taking from there. While in using zip it will stop if iterating that list is exhausted, in this solution can have an index error if list_age is just one more item large.

Answer (score 3):

Use `zip`, to iterate over the matching pairs and update the dicts:

```
>>> for d, a in zip(list_dict, list_age):
...     d["age"] = a
... 
>>> list_dict
[{'id': 1, 'text': 'John', 'age': 23}, {'id': 2, 'text': 'Amy', 'age': 54}, {'id': 3, 'text': 'Ron', 'age': 41}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this loop if `list_age` and `list_dict` are of same length :

```
for i, j in zip(list_dict, list_age):
  i['age']=j
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
[{'id': 1, 'text': 'John', 'age': 23}, {'id': 2, 'text': 'Amy', 'age': 54}, {'id': 3, 'text': 'Ron', 'age': 41}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the list to produce the list of dictionaries:

```py
for a, b in zip(list_dict, list_englishmark):
    a["englishmark"] = b

print(list_dict)
```

Output:

> [{'id': 1, 'name': 'mari', 'englishmark': 80}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Arun', 'englishmark': 54}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'ram', 'englishmark':75}]

Comment: This looks basically identical to three other answers that were posted over a month ago. I don't see what this adds

Comment: @jdd I meant the other answers on this question. Possibly not the accepted one but definitely the other two answers.